# C++ Vector Loop and push_back problem?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I could not figure out what went wrong when I tried to modify vector array. 
Here is my vector array:

```
14248 DL AAAAA
14248 DL AAAAA
14248 DL AAAAA
14248 DL AAAAA
14248
14248
14248
14248
```

What I want to try to do here is, if vector string contains "AAAAA" I will push back as "-" to different vector cRntiModDash. If NOT "AAAAA", then I push back original string.

So, the cRntiModDash vector should be contained after modified:

```
-
-
-
-
-
14248
14248
14248
14248
14248
```

This is what I want, but when I push back to multi-vector all, then something wrong and caused the exit.

```
std::vector<std::vector<string>*> all;
vector<std::string> cRntiModDash;                   
for (vector < string >::iterator ct(cRnti.begin()); ct != cRnti.end(); ct++)
{ 
    std::string cRntTmp (*ct);
    if (cRntTmp.find("AAAAA") != string::npos)
        cRntiModDash.push_back("-");
    else
        cRntiModDash.push_back(*ct);
    }
}
all.push_back(&cRntiModDash);


for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cRnti.size(); j++)
{
  for (std::vector<std::vector<string>*>::iterator i = all.begin(); i != all.end(); i++)
  {
      if (i != all.begin()) 
      {
         CSVToFile << ",";
         std::cout<< ",";
      }
    std::cout<< (**i)[j];
    CSVToFile <<(**i)[j];
  }
  std::cout<< std::endl;
  CSVToFile << std::endl;
}
CSVToFile.close();
```

If I don't modify vector cRnti, then it is OK. I had checked my modified vector did not have any spaces. If someone can recognize my problem, I am really appreciate. I had been tried for while but could not see the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"then something wrong and caused the exit."* - This would be an important part.  You should give as much information on what actually happens as possible, not just "it doesn't work".

Comment: it only printed first CSV line, actually not all data csv line is printed. there are some data are still missing. I know the problem was the modify the DASH "-" since I did try not to modify then it is OK.

Comment: Is this the actual code, or do you have snippets from two or more different functions here?  Also, what is the purpose of `all`?  You only ever push the address of one `vector` on to it - what's it for except to make things needlessly complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector<std::string> cRntiModDash;                   
// ...
all.push_back(&cRntiModDash);
```

You store a pointer to the (presumably) local variable `cRntiModDash` in `all`. As soon as `cRntiModDash` goes out of scope, `all` will contain a pointer to a not longer valid object. That memory location will be reused by other variables and anything might happen when you try to access the vectors in `all` later on.

Comment: Thanks to all for trying to help.

Comment: FYI, those codes above. I have a bunch of vectors for each parameter, and I want to write them to a CSV file. The all vector is KEY. If someone is trying to do that in the future, I hope it can help someone. Unless you have better solution. Thanks again.